# DirectX: How to draw smooth 2D water (particle based water)

Tags: directx, 2d

I recently got a water simulation using particles (1000-1500) working (using the stokes equation), but my problem is that I use a IDXSprite which just draws the particles using blue texture quads (7x7), that doesnt look very smooth.

Is there any way or known technique for drawing such systems so the surface will look smooth (and the water shouldnt have the edges from the textures in it)

Comment: Could you perhaps post a screenshot of what you have, so we have a clear picture of what you want to achieve? I have no idea what your textured-particle-based 2d navier-stokes looks like, or what you want it to look like ("smooth" is rather generic). You might be looking for "2D metaballs" / "marching squares", but that's guessing.